# Cambiar propiedad CSS a elemento dentro de Shadow Root

Tags: css, ionic

Estoy usando Ionic y necesito cambiar la propiedad color de un div (class="calendar-days-of-week") que se encuentra dentro de un shadow-root. Este div es parte de un componente nativo de Ionic por tanto yo no puedo modificarlo como tal.

He probado con los selectores **:host, :host() y :host-context()** pero sin suerte,

lo último que he probado es

```
:host(ion-datetime) .calendar-days-of-week {
    color:white;
  }
```

y llevo ya un buen rato buscando información pero no llego a entender como puedo modificar (si puedo) este div del shadow-dom.

Dejo capturas de pantalla.
Gracias de antemano!!

[image: Div a modificar]

[image: Propiedades CSS]

Comment: Ya probaste con esto ????

div.calendar-days-of-week 
  { 
  color: white;
  }

Comment: Si, ya probé! Y no me funciona

Comment: en herramientas de desarrollador para css, puedes sobre esa clase que te preguntaba si probaste, agregarle **!important** antes del punto y coma, a ver si lo aplica

Answer (score 0):

```
div.calendar-days-of-week { 
     color: white !important; 
}
```

EDITADO:
Lo anterior no funciona debido al shadow dom.

Revisando en otras respuestas, encontré esta similar en ionic con shadow dom, requiere hacerlo via JS.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54855079/12644778

Comment: No lo había probado pero tampoco funciona... gracias!